# values ​with more decimal places than allowed in the database

Tags: mysql

I have a query that is inserting several values ​​from a file to a table. It turns out that in one of the fields in this table it is configured as DECIMAL (20.8) but some of the records contain more than 8 decimal places. I would like to know how do I enter only the 8 decimal places for those values that contain more than 8.

Comment: The database should truncate or round it. Try and find out which one happens.